# JQuery: Binding two event handlers to one button element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I currently wanted to bind two same event handlers(click), that are in different files, to one button element in my html but the second event handler isnt printing any of my debug statements to the console.

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Find it!" id="submit-button">
</form>
```

foobar.js:(this successfully triggers my google maps)

```
$("#submit-button").on("click", function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
});
```

utility.js: (this event handler doesnt do anything):

```
    $("#submit-button").on("click", function(){
      console.log($('#termText').val());
    });
```

I've read from other posts that JQuery should let you bind two event handlers to the same element. But strangely it isnt printing anything for my second click (in utility.js)

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple handlers like this. Make sure you're running all the code in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: You're including both JS files right?

Comment: Does the second one work if you don't do the first one?

Comment: yup! sorry about that. I have both files linked to the html doc @ac

Comment: @exAns - before or after the form html?

Comment: @Barmar hm nope it doesnt. I tried commenting out the first one and keeping the second one but still seems like its not working

Comment: i have my scripts in the head tag (not body)

Comment: Does #termText have a valid val()? Can it just print a string?

Comment: @exAns - then they should both come after jQuery js file and the code fragments you showed must be wrapped in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Either put your scripts at the end of the body, or use `$(document).ready()`. The problem is you're binding the handlers before the DOM element exists.

Comment: that makes sense haha sweet! thanks @i

Comment: @Igor if i wanted to hold a particular order, is there a way i can do that with built-in functionalities from jQuery ?

Comment: "particular order" of what? the order of your two files does not matter (as long as there is no dependency of one on the other). But anything that uses jQuery (or its `$` alias) must come after the `script` tag that links in jQuery javascript.